# Загрузить XML из SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Есть ячейка в sql таблице в которой хранятся данные `varbinary(max)` типа.
Это массив байт xml документа.
Как извлечь и сохранить из всего этого полноценный xml документ?

Добываю эту ячейку таким образом.(не знаю правильно нет)

```
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
            String queryString = "SELECT TOP 1 planGrafik.[myXML] FROM planGrafik WHERE (regNum='03513000925' OR inn='5410126863') ORDER BY vNum DESC";
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, myConnection);
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: @Side Kick лучше добавить этот код в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считывать простые значения из БД вы уже должны уметь - в таком случае получить оттуда XML будет несложно.

Для начала, надо получить массив байт:

```
var bytes = myReader["имя_поля"] as byte[];
if (bytes == null) { /* что-нибудь сделать */ }
```

Теперь надо построить из этого набора байт XML. Для этого можно обернуть их в `MemoryStream` и считать XML из потока:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Если вы предпочитаете использовать XLinq, то `MemoryStream` тоже прекрасно подойдет:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Отдельно отмечу, что способы с предварительным преобразованием в строку являются неверными - поскольку нельзя заранее узнать, в какой кодировке XML записан (кодировка XML по стандарту указывается внутри декларации XML). Кроме того, при использовании UTF-8 и предварительного преобразования в строку возможна проблема с BOM в начале файла.

В случае, если по какой-то причине в базе лежат XML-документы без указания кодировки - можно обернуть `MemoryStream` в `StreamReader`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes), Encoding.ВашаКодировка));

var doc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes), Encoding.ВашаКодировка));
```

Но в таких случаях я рекомендую сменить тип колонки с `varbinary` на `nvarchar`! Работать с ним будет еще проще:

```
var xmlstr = myReader["имя_поля"] as string;
if (xmlstr == null) { /* что-нибудь сделать */ }

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstr);

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А не подскажите как сохранить этот xml?=)

Comment: @SideKick Сохранить куда? Обратно в базу, или в файл?

Comment: @SideKick вот вам полезные ссылки: [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: сохранить в файл. Извиняюсь за свою тупость просто для меня это все новое...

Comment: @SideKick обычно для сохранения используют метод Save

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])reader[<индекс вашего столбца>];//1
    string xml = Encoding.<Кодировка вашего файла>.GetString(buffer) //Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);                
}
```

Все что в треугольных скобках заменяем на реальные данные (скобки тоже нафиг).

Comment: У этого способа есть проблемы с кодировками. Во-первых, он требует угадывания кодировки. Во-вторых, может быть проблема с начальным BOM, если документ в UTF-8.

Comment: @Mirdin в buffer должен быть массив байт?(данные из ячейки SQL)

Comment: @SideKick, да в буфере массив байт

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если у нас массив байт, то нам всегда придется играть в угадайку. Лучше было бы конечно не varbinary, а xml(если он есть), varchar и то был бы лучше.

Comment: @Mirdin не придется. По стандарту, кодировка XML пишется в декларации XML, а при отсутствии указания кодировки используется UTF-8.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если у нас varbinary, то мы даже не можем гарантировать что там лежит текст, а не допустим изображение, куда там кодировкам.

Comment: @Mirdin то, что внутри лежит XML - известно. Не переусложняйте.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если мы работаем с "нашей" базой данных, то ни в какую угадайку нам играть не придется -- мы знаем что хранится, мы знаем в какой кодировке. Если с "чужой" -- varbinary, это проблема, даже если допустить что там хранятся только xml, не факт что при сохранении они не перекодировались, поэтому, нам в любом случае, понадобиться какая либо функция определяющая(угадывающая) кодировку, но это уже далеко за гранью вопроса.

Comment: @Mirdin возможен вариант, когда в базу записывается файл, пришедший "снаружи". В таком случае он может быть в *любой* кодировке. Но при этом кодировка в декларации обязана быть правильной - иначе это уже не наши проблемы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44339/discussion-between-mirdin-and-pavel-mayorov).